# Having trouble sending a json to html and getting <%- to work

Tags: json, express, ejs

So I'm trying to use values in my json file to display on the webpage. For instance, one value will be the text on the accordion button.

I'm using express and ejs, and I've been trying to use <%- %> to call the text in the json file but it won't seem to appear on the webpage.

index.js

```
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.locals.ClinNotes1=('.\ClinNotes.json');
     res.render('webpage');
     })
```

webpage.ejs

```
<div id="Problems" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="problemItems">
    <button class="accordion" id="accordionDis">
    <span><ul><%-ClinNotes1.resourceType%></ul></span>
```

ClinNotes.json

```
{ "resourceType": "Bundle",
....}
```

Comment: Any suggestions would be very helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show your **JSON** data on your webpage you can do something like that:

**index.js**

```
//here import your json file

const notes = require('./ClinNotes.json'); //suppose your file is in the root directory

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('webpage', {data: notes});
 })
```

**webpage.ejs**

```
 <span><ul><%-data.resourceType%></ul></span>
```

Hopefully, it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example I put together.

Basically, you want to iterate over the JSON file the same way you would a Javascript object.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Use EJS Templating Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.dataFromJSON = require('./data.json');
  res.render('index');
});

//Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port number ${port}`);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hope this helps!</h1>
  <% Object.values(dataFromJSON).forEach((value) => { %>
  <button><%= value %></button>
  <% }); %>
</body>

</html>
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "resourceType2": "Bundle2",
  "resourceType3": "Bundle3",
  "resourceType4": "Bundle4"
}
```

[Here is a gitub repo i created](https://github.com/chrisdav6/expressLoopOverJSON)

[Here is the expected output deployed to heroku](https://looping-over-json-in-express.herokuapp.com/)

I hope this helps!